# JS Variable Scope Lookup vs Allocation

Tags: javascript

If I am applying a function to a javascript array i.e.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var x;

a.forEach(function(val) {
    x = val + 1;
    // do some stuff with x        
});
```

Is it better to leave the variable declaration in the outer scope or to put the declaration inside the function? i.e.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];

a.forEach(function(val) {
    var x = val + 1;
    // do some stuff with x
});
```

What I do not know is if the memory allocation for x is more expensive than the variable lookup process.

Comment: Usually, that is really not something to worry about in terms of memory.

Comment: Variable declared outside callback will be accessed by one more lookup as compared to declared inside. However if your array is not very large, I think it won't make any difference.

Comment: As the others put it; you usually should not be worried about the memory. In your first example however, ```x``` *will* be accessible after your function call, whereas ```x``` in your second example is scoped to just that function.

Comment: Also, the JS engine does a lot of optimization around such things anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the variable outside the `forEach` callback, put it inside. It is simply cleaner that way. Memory is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to put it into the loop. There is no performance difference. However using the scope the right way is a good starting point to detect errors:

```
  var something = 5;

  a.forEach(el => something = el);

  console.log(something); // what is something? Why is it set?
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I do not know is if the memory allocation for x is more expensive than the variable lookup process

**It depends**. It depends on the exact code, the size of the array, how frequently the code is run, how many scopes there are between the code accessing the variable and the scope where the variable is declared, what optimizations the JavaScript engine on which the code is running does, etc.

**So**: Write the clearest, simplest code you can, and ***if*** you run into a performance problem related to that code, profile changes to see how to address it. Anything else is premature optimization and a waste of your time.

**However**: With the example given, if you declare it within the callback, `x` will be a local stack variable, and those are **extremely** cheap to allocate (in terms of execution time). I can't see that it would really matter either way (if you declare it outside, it's just one scope away), but it happens that in this case, the simplest, cleanest code (declaring it within the callback) is at least likely not to be *worse* than the alternative, and I'd say almost certainly better. But again: If it's an issue, profile the real code.

Comment: Thanks. I was truly just asking as a curiosity. Based on the responses stackoverflow wasn't the right place for this.

Comment: @gph: Theory questions are fine here as far as I know. But yes, when people see what they think is premature micro-optimization, the pragmatic hats go on. :-) Anyway, FWIW, I'd be really surprised if declaring it within the callback were slower than declaring it outside.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, of course is is slower to declare (*n* times) inside cb with gc, than outside, but i would moce it inside if no use outside is required.

Comment: @NinaScholz: No GC required (other than popping the stack, which happens anyway), `x` will be a stack variable on any modern engine (unless we assume a closure created by the callback that endures after it exits, and there's no indication of that in the OP's code). The act of exiting the callback reclaims it, when you pop the stack.

Comment: [This jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/variable-inside-or-outside-callback) suggests that inside the callback is indeed (a very little bit) faster.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, this change control two parameters: Scope and initiation.
Scope: if you need to use this var outside the loop, so you need to declare it out side, else you can drop it in and each iteration and the scope will declare, its probably saves memory outside the scope.
Initiation: in big programs the initiation can be critic time,
each time who the loop takes place you need to declare the var and its wasting time...